# Filtering through json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

It represents the trade offer from steam. Every offer has "items_to_give" and "items_to_receive".

I want this json array to look like this

```
{
"items_to_give": [
                {
                    "market_hash_name": "AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
                },
                {
                    "market_hash_name": "M4A4 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)"  
                }
                 ]
            ,

"items_to_receive": [
                {
                    "market_hash_name": "★ Falchion Knife | Blue Steel (Field-Tested)"
                }                      
                    ]
}
```

Every item has unique "classid" and "instanceid" but their "market_hash_name" is shown in "descriptions" part of array.

First I have to find their name using "classid" and "instanceid" and than move it to the "items_to_give" and "items_to_receive" .

Here is the photo showing what i mean .
[image]

Comment: haven't you tried anything yet? first, since you already have the raw input, turn it into an array, select those things you need and structure them as you'd like them to and put then in another container, treat it as any normal array, then encode it again

Comment: i have not tryed anything. I dont have any idea how to do it. For now i have this $url = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v0001/?key=MYKEY&get_received_offers=1&active_only=1&get_descriptions=1";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

Comment: @Ghost Thanks for idea, I ll try.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting your question here, and welcome to Stack Overflow! In case you don't know, a question statement is a sentence in an interrogative form followed by a question mark. We require that question posts contain question statements, which yours does not. Please take the [tour], check out the [help/on-topic], and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a file and test it. I think you can do it.

**The Result is like this:**

```
{
    "items_to_give": [
        {
            "instanceid": "480085569",
            "classid": "1440311074",
            "assetid": "5003822520",
            "amount": "1",
            "market_hash_name": "AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
            "market_name": "AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
            "name": "AWP | Asiimov",
            "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAR17PLfYQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7c2G9SupUijOjAotyg3w2x_0ZkZ2rzd4OXdgRoYQuE8gDtyL_mg5K4tJ7XiSw0WqKv8kM",
            "action_link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D9394689721994738281"
        },
        {
            "instanceid": "188530139",
            "classid": "310777979",
            "assetid": "4999225449",
            "amount": "1",
            "market_hash_name": "M4A4 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
            "market_name": "M4A4 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
            "name": "M4A4 | Asiimov",
            "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou-6kejhjxszFJQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7c2GlUucFwjruR9t7231DmrRc_NW7yItCRcVNoYVHS-APrwbzu0JK-78nXiSw0EnwDRM0",
            "action_link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D459488816407887944"
        }
    ],
    "items_to_receive": [
        {
            "instanceid": "188530139",
            "classid": "1015898744",
            "assetid": "5004700589",
            "amount": "1",
            "market_hash_name": "\u2605 Falchion Knife | Blue Steel (Field-Tested)",
            "market_name": "\u2605 Falchion Knife | Blue Steel (Field-Tested)",
            "name": "\u2605 Falchion Knife | Blue Steel",
            "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf1fLEcjVL49KJlZG0lfvhNr_um25V4dB8xOrApdqmjAbi_hFtYGr7cICUdVVtNA6D81m9yObr0cDotJnJnSM3viU8pSGKmL5fGRg",
            "action_link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D14288283571522546212"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

I put also some needed on this code. Because I am a steam user also.:D

```
<?php
$steamResponse = '{
    "response": {
        "trade_offers_received": [
            {
                "tradeofferid": "993371789",
                "accountid_other": 254083372,
                "message": "I just got a fantastic idea. This could make everything good between us.          ;)",
                "expiration_time": 1455660736,
                "trade_offer_state": 7,
                "items_to_give": [
                    {
                        "appid": "730",
                        "contextid": "2",
                        "assetid": "5003822520",
                        "classid": "1440311074",
                        "instanceid": "480085569",
                        "amount": "1",
                        "missing": false
                    },
                    {
                        "appid": "730",
                        "contextid": "2",
                        "assetid": "4999225449",
                        "classid": "310777979",
                        "instanceid": "188530139",
                        "amount": "1",
                        "missing": false
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "items_to_receive": [
                    {
                        "appid": "730",
                        "contextid": "2",
                        "assetid": "5004700589",
                        "classid": "1015898744",
                        "instanceid": "188530139",
                        "amount": "1",
                        "missing": false
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "is_our_offer": false,
                "time_created": 1454451136,
                "time_updated": 1454451250,
                "from_real_time_trade": false,
                "escrow_end_date": 0,
                "confirmation_method": 0
            }
        ]
        ,
        "descriptions": [
            {
                "appid": 730,
                "classid": "1440311074",
                "instanceid": "480085569",
                "currency": false,
                "background_color": "",
                "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAR17PLfYQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7c2G9SupUijOjAotyg3w2x_0ZkZ2rzd4OXdgRoYQuE8gDtyL_mg5K4tJ7XiSw0WqKv8kM",
                "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot621FAR17PLfYQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7cqWdQ-sJ0xOzAot-jiQa3-hBqYzvzLdSVJlQ3NQvR-FfsxL3qh5e7vM6bzSA26Sg8pSGKJUPeNtY",
                "descriptions": [
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "Exterior: Field-Tested"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "High risk and high reward, the infamous AWP is recognizable by its signature report and one-shot, one-kill policy. It has been custom painted with a sci-fi design.\n\n<i>Anyone can predict the future... a visionary shapes it</i>"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "The Phoenix Collection",
                        "color": "9da1a9"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "<br><div id=\"sticker_info\" name=\"sticker_info\" title=\"Sticker Details\" style=\"border: 2px solid rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 6px; width=100; margin:4px; padding:8px;\"><center><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/team_roles_capsule/baiter.f14ba197e75a0b0074c74e7f98af9eb4d111981b.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/team_roles_capsule/lurker.850f26af6a1e55f4ed398da610d9ceb73ce0b338.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/team_roles_capsule/awper.251e754fcfd1d398fcedc220dc44f479b841c8ea.png\"><br>Sticker: The Baiter, The Lurker, The Awper</center></div>"
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "tradable": true,
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D9394689721994738281",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "name": "AWP | Asiimov",
                "name_color": "D2D2D2",
                "type": "Covert Sniper Rifle",
                "market_name": "AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
                "market_hash_name": "AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
                "market_actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D9394689721994738281",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "commodity": false,
                "market_tradable_restriction": 7
            },
            {
                "appid": 730,
                "classid": "310777979",
                "instanceid": "188530139",
                "currency": false,
                "background_color": "",
                "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou-6kejhjxszFJQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7c2GlUucFwjruR9t7231DmrRc_NW7yItCRcVNoYVHS-APrwbzu0JK-78nXiSw0EnwDRM0",
                "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou-6kejhjxszFJQJD_9W7m5a0mvLwOq7cqWdQ-sJ0xOvEpIj0jAbkqEE_ZD3xctLGJAE_Zw7U-QTowefth8TpvM_InHZh6XQ8pSGKWYJAoJI",
                "descriptions": [
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "Exterior: Field-Tested"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "More accurate but less damaging than its AK-47 counterpart, the M4A4 is the full-auto assault rifle of choice for CTs. It has been custom painted with a sci-fi design.\n\n<i>Anyone can predict the future... a visionary shapes it</i>"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "The Winter Offensive Collection",
                        "color": "9da1a9"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "tradable": true,
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D459488816407887944",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "name": "M4A4 | Asiimov",
                "name_color": "D2D2D2",
                "type": "Covert Rifle",
                "market_name": "M4A4 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
                "market_hash_name": "M4A4 | Asiimov (Field-Tested)",
                "market_actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D459488816407887944",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "commodity": false,
                "market_tradable_restriction": 7
            },
            {
                "appid": 730,
                "classid": "1015898744",
                "instanceid": "188530139",
                "currency": false,
                "background_color": "",
                "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf1fLEcjVL49KJlZG0lfvhNr_um25V4dB8xOrApdqmjAbi_hFtYGr7cICUdVVtNA6D81m9yObr0cDotJnJnSM3viU8pSGKmL5fGRg",
                "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf1fLEcjVL49KJlZG0lfvhNr_um25V4dB8teXA54vwxle1-0VvN2v1IdSUcQU2NV7R_QLtlLi8jJ6_tZXNnSQ3siQisS6JmxCpwUYbIOval6A",
                "descriptions": [
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "Exterior: Field-Tested"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": "A modern homage to a falchion sword, this clip point blade has a curved edge. It has been cold blued.\n\n<i>This is the malbec of weapon design - Booth, Arms Dealer</i>"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "html",
                        "value": " "
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "tradable": true,
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D14288283571522546212",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "name": "★ Falchion Knife | Blue Steel",
                "name_color": "8650AC",
                "type": "★ Covert Knife",
                "market_name": "★ Falchion Knife | Blue Steel (Field-Tested)",
                "market_hash_name": "★ Falchion Knife | Blue Steel (Field-Tested)",
                "market_actions": [
                    {
                        "link": "steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D14288283571522546212",
                        "name": "Inspect in Game..."
                    }
                ]
                ,
                "commodity": false,
                "market_tradable_restriction": 7
            }
        ]

    }
}';


$json = json_decode($steamResponse); // $steamResponse is the json response from steam

$result = array();
$result['items_to_give'] = array();
$result['items_to_receive'] = array();


foreach($json->response->trade_offers_received[0]->items_to_give as $key => $value){
    $result['items_to_give'][$key]['instanceid'] = $value->instanceid;
    $result['items_to_give'][$key]['classid'] = $value->classid;
    $result['items_to_give'][$key]['assetid'] = $value->assetid;
    $result['items_to_give'][$key]['amount'] = $value->amount;

    foreach($json->response->descriptions as $key2 => $value2){
        if(($value2->instanceid == $value->instanceid) && ($value2->classid == $value->classid)){
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['market_hash_name'] = $value2->market_hash_name;
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['market_name'] = $value2->market_name;
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['name'] = $value2->name;
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['icon_url'] = $value2->icon_url;
            $result['items_to_give'][$key]['action_link'] = $value2->actions[0]->link;
        }
    }
}

foreach($json->response->trade_offers_received[0]->items_to_receive as $key => $value){
    $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['instanceid'] = $value->instanceid;
    $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['classid'] = $value->classid;
    $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['assetid'] = $value->assetid;
    $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['amount'] = $value->amount;
    foreach($json->response->descriptions as $key2 => $value2){
        if(($value2->instanceid == $value->instanceid) && ($value2->classid == $value->classid)){
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['market_hash_name'] = $value2->market_hash_name;
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['market_name'] = $value2->market_name;
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['name'] = $value2->name;
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['icon_url'] = $value2->icon_url;
            $result['items_to_receive'][$key]['action_link'] = $value2->actions[0]->link;
        }
    }
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Perfect , thanks. I tested this today, i didnt have time before to test it .

Answer (score 0):

First convert your JSON to PHP

```
$response = json_decode($json, true);
```

A good way to traverse nested data is to use PHP's `array_*` functions. That's why I converted to associative array rather than objects.

Now create a function to fetch IDs by *give* or *receive*:

```
function classIds($index, $response)
{
    return array_map(function ($item) { return $item["classid"]; }, $response["response"]["trade_offers_received"][0]["items_to_" . $index]);
}
```

And another function to fetch descriptions for those IDs:

```
function descriptionForIds($ids, $response)
{
    return array_map(
        // After finding matching IDs return their market hash name
        function ($description) {
            return [ "market_hash_name" => $description["market_hash_name"] ];
        },
        // Find matching IDs
        array_filter(
            $response["response"]["descriptions"],
            function ($description) use ($ids) { return in_array($description["classid"], $ids); }
        )
    );
}
```

Build up the result array using these functions:

```
$result = [
    "items_to_give" => descriptionForIds(classIds("give", $response), $response),
    "items_to_receive" => descriptionForIds(classIds("receive", $response), $response),
];
```

And back to JSON:

```
json_encode($result);
```